# Right Data Structure for Cascading Controls

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

Suppose I had a series of tables in a database with (for example purposes) information about the menu items in a series of restaurants. 
So, for example, we have, say 10 tables:

```
Rest_1, Rest_2, Rest_3, .... Rest_10 
(Names being more complex, though, in the real situation)
```

And every table has the EXACT SAME column structure, say (Just making this up for illustration purposes, so forgive the weakness of the example):

```
Col1 (Primary Key) = Menu_Item
Col2               = Menu_Category  (Desert, Appetizer, ...)
Col3               = Item_Cost
Col4               = Item_SalePrice
Col5               = Item_Popularity
Col6               = Seasonal_Item  (Boolean - Is it seasonal)
Col7               = Min_Order      (Boolean - Is there a minimum order from the vendor)  
Col8               = In_Stock       (Boolean - Is it in stock now)  
....
```

Now, I have a Windows Form with, say, 3 comboBoxes and a checkbox:

```
cboRestaurant
cboMenuCategory
cboPopularity
ckInStock
```

And a DataView which, based upon what the user chooses above, shows the correct (filtered) information which can then be used for processing something.

So, my situation is that we would:

1. Populate the Restaurant combobox
2. Based upon the user's selection of cboRestaurant & the ckInStock.checked status, populate the cboMenuCategory combobox
3. Based upon 1 & 2, populate the cboPopularity combobox
4. Based upon what user chose for all the comboboxes / checkbox, populate the dataview.

... Again, I know this is a weak example, but I'm trying to convey the concept.

---

So... Based upon what I've picked up online, what I'm seeing as being the best case to accomplish this would be to:

1. Query each Table and store the results in a DataTable  (This I can do)
2. Store those datatables in a Dataset                    (This I can do)

What I don't know how to do is to let the dataset know how all the datatables are related (All have the same column names) **AND** bind the comboboxes to the dataset such as to filter the information based upon what was selected in the previous combobox.

### OR

Create a list(of custom object) that will hold all these variables from all the tables and then Linq-Query that list based upon the `combobox.SelectedIndexChanged` \ `ckInStock.CheckedChanged` events - this seems much worse since we're constantly querying and re-querying.

---

### So, my first question is:

If solution #1 is right, how do I create the conglomerated dataset and have the comboboxes have the correct filtered data based upon the preceding comboboxes and checkbox value?

### My Second question is:

Is there just a better way to accomplish this IN TOTAL that I just don't know about - A built in better object that does the cascading filtering for you, or how best to accomlish this otherwise?

Comment: The term for this is "cascading dropdowns."  You'll find a lot of help if you do [an Internet search for that term](https://www.google.com/search?q=cascading+dropdowns+c%23).

Comment: Thanks, Robert - I got the original idea by reading up on Cascading Dropdowns, but still am having major issues with the data binding / Only getting unique values into the comboBoxes, etc... Does anyone know of an example similar to mine I could learn from / could anyone offer some guidance?? Thanks!